# Generate title within printed download url via youtube-dl

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, youtube-dl

I'm trying to get youtube video link **with `&title=Video+Title`**.

I've tried to use this cmd line:

```
youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A" -q -g --get-filename -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

But the result is without `&title=Adele+-+Hello`.

```
https://r5---sn-uxaxjvhxbt2u-j5pd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ratebypass=yes&fexp=9416126%2C9416681%2C9420452%2C9421527%2C9422596%2C9422672%2C9423662%2C9424298%2C9425865%2C9426226%2C9426654%2C9427167&itag=22&sparams=dur%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&initcwndbps=72500&id=o-AENDqUSOQKUWY9Cpdyen_8bWvjzhr4xV7j_XYKxB9Stb&mn=sn-uxaxjvhxbt2u-j5pd&mm=31&ipbits=0&ms=au&dur=366.875&mv=m&mt=1452900178&ip=*MY_IP*&lmt=1445682343305162&gcr=eg&requiressl=yes&sver=3&expire=1452921952&upn=XazM4GTA-T4&key=yt6&source=youtube&pl=20&mime=video%2Fmp4&signature=D9F01CE5C80332BAA7903C46CDAF6F5DB7CACD9D.5995772178A1C8D49A1A5DE3058D732F5889742D
Adele - Hello.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p input="Input URL: "
youtube-dl "%input%"
```

try above in bat file 
note use it in same folder as youtube.dl.exe

Comment: Not related at all to my question.